# How can we compute $\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-\cdots}}}$? Is it $\frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How can we compute $\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-\cdots}}}$?

I can understand that if we define  $a_1=\sqrt{4}$ and $a_n=\sqrt{4-a_{n-1}}$ for $n>1$ which gives (also using with monotone convergent theorem) $$\lim a_n=\frac{\sqrt{17}-1}2.$$ But we can write it as $a_1=\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4}}$ and then $a_n=\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-a_{n-1}}}}$.

If there is a limit $L$ (I think we can use monotone convergent theorem), I solved with Wolfram that $$L=\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-L}}}$$ and it compute $L=\frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{2}$ again.

But I saw kind of continued fraction and gives different answers. (I sware, but not necessary, finding examples are not hard).

Is  there a definition of this kind of nested numbers{?!}/limits?

Comment: $\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4}}=\sqrt{4-2}=\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Yes, I was editting and still editing :)

Comment: The correct recursion is $a_n=\sqrt{4-a_{n-1}}$, not $\sqrt{4-\sqrt{a_{n-1}}}$ (and begins with $a_1=\sqrt4$, not $a_1=4$).

Comment: @BarryCipra, If it is correct, why? :)

Comment: @studentforever, because $a_n=\sqrt{4-a_{n-1}}=\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-a_{n-2}}}=\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-a_{n-3}}}}=...$

Comment: The sequence $(a_n)$ is defined recursively by $a_{n+1}=F(a_n)$ and the question is to prove that $a_n\to a_*$ where $a_*$ is the unique fixed point of $F$ on $[0,4]$. To do so, the usual approach is to find some interval $I$ around $a_*$ such that $|F'|\leqslant r$ on $I$, for some $r<1$, to check that some $a_k$ is in $I$ and to deduce that $|a_{n+k}-a_*|\leqslant r^n\cdot|a_k-a_*|$, which proves the desired result. In the end, this works if $|F'(a_*)|<1$. In the present case, $F'(a_*)=-1/(2F(a_*))=-1/(2a_*)$ hence $|F'(a_*)|=1/(\sqrt{17}-1)<1/3$ and everything is fine.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I recognize me fault now, thanks, @BarryCipra. But I calculate the limit as $L=\sqrt{4-L}$. This is why I supposed it is true. It was $\sqrt{4-a_{n-1}}$ in my brain.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** This answer explains exactly how one can compute the value A of the expression in question. It was written prior to a clarification by the OP that mathematical context was the main intent of the question, and does not constitute a full answer to the question, as such. I will leave it here because it has apparently been found useful by some.

$A=\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-\cdots}}}$

$A^2=4-\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-\cdots}}}$

$\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-\cdots}}}=4-A^2$

$A=4-A^2$

$A^2+A-4=0$

$A=\frac{-1±\sqrt{1-4(1)(-4)}}{2(1)}$

$A=\frac{-1±\sqrt{17}}{2}$

And naturally, the square root being negative is an extraneous solutions, so the value is

$A=\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{2}$

Comment: Could someone help explain to me the down vote? I am fairly certain this working is helpful and correct...

Comment: My question is not related with your answer. Moreover, I wasnt the down-voter :)

Comment: Well, I was answering your first question. "How can we compute...?". I think an answer with regards to your second question, regarding limits would complement nicely with this answer.

Comment: No. "How can we compute"  means "Where it comes from, matematically".

Comment: I think that might be a helpful edit to the text of the question. I'll leave my answer because it might be helpful to some who are in fact looking for a way to compute what the expression is equal to, but I'm sorry if it isn't an answer to your actual question.

Comment: Doesn't look downvoteable to me.  The extraneous root is actually not all that extraneous.  Reverse the signs on _all_ the square roots and note what you get.  We can say that the two roots are characteristic of a pattern where the leading square root has  one sign but all others have the opposite sign.

Comment: This identifies the limit if the limit exists. My understanding is that the OP asks for a proof that the limit exists.

Comment: Right the OP clarified that for me. I originally though the OP's confusion centered around finding the limit itself. (See 'EDIT' above)

Comment: Thanks for your edit part. @Did, I am asking how can we choose the sequence or do we need to choose sequence(which makes bad of course, I think we need to choose at least a sequence).

Comment: I would downvote if I could. It's just some symbol manipulation without any justification.

Comment: Well, I agree that its justification is dependent on the limit existing; I had the original misconception to think that we were clear put o that point...